# Salesforce Object Specific Action height not setting correctly

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have an object specific action in lightning that opens a visualforce page.  When creating the action I am able to set the height of the action modal but when it actually loads only a small portion of the modal is available to the VF page.

[image]

I thought maybe some rouge css was causing this so I took out all my markup and replaced it with text.  The problem still persists.

Did I miss a step setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared my cache, reloaded the page, and it worked.

Very strange, but good to know.